# trying to enable the latest quiz level from DB when user logs in in react js

Tags: reactjs, algorithm, debugging

I have logic for disabling and enabling level buttons such as rookie,student,interm,expert,master etc. what i want is to send the data to db so that when user logs out and logs back in he is in the latest level eg if he was doing level expert and logs out. when he logs in he should have all the button enabled till expert since thats where he left off. im confused on which how to assign the data from db to the state.

this is the buttons

```
 <Button
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.changeToquiz1();
                    this.articelState();
                  }}
                >
                  Rookie
                </Button>
                <Button
                  disabled={this.state.level < STUDENT}
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.articelState();
                    this.changeToquiz2();
                  }}
                >
                  Student
                </Button>
                <Button
                  disabled={this.state.level < INTERM}
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.changeToquiz3();
                    this.articelState();
                  }}
                >
                  Intermediate
                </Button>
                <Button
                  disabled={this.state.level < EXPERT}
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.changeToquiz4();
                    this.articelState();
                  }}
                >
                  Expert
                </Button>
                <Button
                  disabled={this.state.level < MASTER}
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.changeToquiz5();
                    this.articelState();
                  }}
                >
                  Master
                </Button>
```

this is the logic for enabling/disabling

```
handleDisableValue = scores => {
    if (scores >= 5 && this.state.level < 4) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        level: this.state.level + 1
      }));
    }
   // console.log(this.state.level);
  };
```

this is in the render part

```
const STUDENT = 1;
    const INTERM = 2;
    const EXPERT = 3;
    const MASTER = 4;
```

DB call to retrive the data
 im interested in rank only

```
    retrieveData = () => {
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        var ref = fire
          .database()
          .ref("data")
          .limitToLast(1);
        //takes the last data in DB

        var userUID = fire.auth().currentUser.uid;
        var query = ref.orderByChild("ID").equalTo(userUID); //retrieves data about only the current logged in user
        console.log(userUID);
        query.once("value", snapshot => {
          let currentState = this.state.people;

          const currentUser = snapshot.val();
          for (let i in currentUser) {
            currentState.push({
              email: currentUser[i].UserEmail,
              UserAnswer: currentUser[i].UserAnswer,
              Questions: currentUser[i].Question,
              id: currentUser[i].ID,
              Score: currentUser[i].Score,
              levelRook: currentUser[i].UserLevel,
              levelStudent: currentUser[i].UserLevelStudent,
              levelIntermediate: currentUser[i].UserLevelIntermediate,
              levelExpert: currentUser[i].UserLevelExpert,
              levelMaster: currentUser[i].UserLevelMaster,
              rank: currentUser[i].RankValue
            });
          }
          // this.setState({
          // level: this.state.rank
          // });

          // currentState.push(user);
          console.log(currentState);

          this.setState({
            people: currentState,
            dataHasLoaded: true
            //  level: rank
          });
        });
      } else {
        console.log("no user");
      }
    });
  };
```

any help on this please thanks

Comment: Where is your database call?

Comment: @goto1 sorry its here -- rank: currentUser[i].RankValue this has the rank value (has values between 1to 4)but not sure where to use it

Comment: include all the relevant code in your example, it's hard to figure out what the issue is without the rest of your code

Comment: what you're showing is just a `for` loop, where's the rest? What are you trying to use inside `currentUser[idx]` that you want to store in the `state`? Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? Right now what I am seeing is pieces but it's hard to get the full picture.

Comment: @goto1 see updated

Comment: If you are only getting information about the current user that's logged in, why are you saving it in `this.state.people`? Why not just to create a new property inside of `this.state` that relates to the `authUser`, for example `this.state.authUser` and then just update `state.authUser` when the `firebase` call finishes? Then for `disabled` on each button use `this.state.authUser.rank`.

Comment: @goto1 i dont understand can u show me an example of it with above code i have

Comment: @goto1 also i dont get when you are saying "just update state.authUser when the firebase call finishes? " can u show me a code snippet of it please to get a better understandment

Comment: A very simplified example would look something like this - https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-turing-1vj6z?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark